# (С++) Возможность принятия лямбда выражения как параметра функции

Tags: c++, функции

Задача: реализовать функцию, которая может принять лямбда-выражение(анонимную функцию) как параметр.
Например у меня есть функция

```
void f(**что будет здесь?**){
 //какой-то код
 //вызов лямбда выражения
 //и еще какой-то код
}

int main(){
 //а здесь я хочу вызвать функцию f и передать ей лямбда-выражение в качестве параметра
 f([](){cout<<"Ура, заработало!";});
}
```

Comment: Чистый С++?

Comment: Да, вот например for_each из STL 3-им параметром может принимать лямбду, просто синтаксис не могу до конца понять

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот такое получилось на коленке

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*func)();

void f(func t){
 //какой-то код
 //вызов лямбда выражения
 //и еще какой-то код
 t();
}

int main(){
 //а здесь я хочу вызвать функцию f и передать ей лямбда-выражение в качестве параметра
 f([](){cout<<"Ура, заработало!";});
}
```

учитывая замечания [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), добавлю ещё один рабочий вариант.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void f(const function<void()> t){
 //какой-то код
 //вызов лямбда выражения
 //и еще какой-то код
 t();
}

int main(){
 //а здесь я хочу вызвать функцию f и передать ей лямбда-выражение в качестве параметра
 f([](){cout<<"Ура, заработало!";});
}
```

и [ссылочку](http://www.nullptr.me/2011/10/12/c11-lambda-having-fun-with-brackets/).

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, к указателю на функцию приводится лишь лямбда с пустым списком захваченных переменных.

Comment: Благодарю! С std::functional все взлетело

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендованный метод такой:

1) Используйте `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
void output(const function<string(int)>& f)
{
    cout << f(0) << endl;
}

string text = "text";
output([&](int i){ return text; });
```

2) Или, чтобы избежать создания дополнительного объекта, используйте шаблоны.

```
template<typename F>
void output(const F& f)
{
    cout << f(0) << endl;
}
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/UKYmip).

Comment: Ваш вариант конечно хорош, но у него есть один недостаток. Он не решает задачу @snakext.

Comment: Благодарю на подсказку с std::functional.